# Derive Keras Cosine Restarts Scheduler Formula from Source Code

Tags: machine-learning, keras, mathematics, code

I used Keras implementation of the cosine restarts algorithm. I need to know the exact formula of the algorithm for my LaTeX manuscript. The documentation is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/CosineDecayRestarts). The implementation differs (in terms of parameters) from the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03983) they reference. I am not able to derive the formula from [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.13.1/keras/optimizers/schedules/learning_rate_schedule.py#L774) myself. Is someone able to help me with that? I tried feeding Chat-GPT with it but I can't verify the result.